# Client validate non-model bound checkbox while using MVC 2 jQuery Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

**Have:** Using ASP.NET MVC 2, DataAnnotationsModel based server validation, and client validation with jQuery.  Anything in my model is validated perfectly on the client with jQuery based validation (jQuery.validate and MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js).

**Need:** Adding an additional HTML `<input type="checkbox" id="terms" />` to my form.  I need jQuery validation to require that this checkbox is checked AND somehow hook it in with whatever jQuery client script MVC is automagically controlling.  Yes, I know it won't validate on the server side, but I don't need or want it to.

Seems like it *should* be simple but I'm new to MVC, a total beginner at jQuery, and my searches have been coming up blank.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I suggest using a ViewModel for every View (put all of your dataannotations in there). Then you can create a boolean model property for your checkbox and set it to required.

From there, if you're posting the model back to the controller, you can simply use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map the ViewModel to the needed model, or simply map the properties yourself.

Either way, it is good practice to use a ViewModel for every view. Remember a ViewModel's job is to try and contain everything required in the view. This definitely means that it can and will have other data that is not required in the Model.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid all this because I'd also have to create a custom validator class, register it in global.asax, bla, bla.... too much work for one little checkbox whose value I didn't need to store anyway.  But I see no way around it and this is what I had to do.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're willing to upgrade to MVC 3, you can build a validator controller instead of a custom validator. Then you can use [remote validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28VS.98%29.aspx) for your client side stuff.

Comment: That would be ideal but I'm stuck on a .NET 3.5 platform.  However, it turns out I didn't need a custom validator.  I assumed I would because I thought jQuery would just evaluate the text value (true or false) and see it was not an empty string, therefore fulfilling the DataAnnotation 'Required' requirement.  I was wrong.  Using
`[Required(ErrorMessage = "Checkbox must be checked")]` actually worked and was evaluated correctly by jQuery; no custom validator needed

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution. It mimics what mvc does to hook into jQuery validation. So there's a checkbox called Accept that doesn't belong to the model. The script must go after the form and it adds all the validation meta data for that field.

```
    <%
        Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
    <% using(Html.BeginForm("Show"))
{ %>
      <%= Html.EditorForModel() %>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.CheckBox("Accept", new { @class = "required" })%> 
        <span class="field-validation-valid" id="Accept_validationMessage"></span>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<%} %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.mvcClientValidationMetadata[0].Fields.push({
        FieldName: "Accept",
        ReplaceValidationMessageContents: true,
        ValidationMessageId: "Accept_validationMessage",
        ValidationRules: [{ ErrorMessage: "The Accept field is required.", ValidationType: "required", ValidationParameters: {}}]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This gets me closer but the validation for this checkbox seems to be competing with MVC's auto-wired jQuery validation event.  What is happening is I see the client validation message for the new checkbox but then the validation messages for all the other fields disappear.

Comment: @Justin I've set up a test page that has an Html.EditorFor() statement and an extra checkbox with the class="required" and I don't see the competing messages. Perhaps you can post your aspx and JS code.

Comment: Would there be any JS code for this?  Doesn't the jQuery.validate library use `class="required"` attribute of the checkbox to hook up a form submittal validation check?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //// Assuming your form's ID is 'form0'
    $("#form0").submit(function() {  
        if ($("#terms").attr('checked')) {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
           //// Error message if any
           return false;
        }
    });
});
```